# Pausing a loop to run another in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a circuit that has two separate 4-bit binary counters with LEDs. I press a button and one counter begins counting to 15 in binary. I press a second button and the first counter pauses where it is and the second group of LEDs begin counting to 15 in binary. I got both counters working, but I can't get the first group to pause and the second to begin. I've tried using if statements with a boolean flag, but it messes up the first group of LEDs. How can I get ledPins1[] to pause when button2 is pressed, then resume when ledPins2[] finish?

```
int ledPin1[] = {2,3,4,5};
int ledPin2[] = {7,8,9,10};
int button1 = 11;
int button2 = 12;
boolean button1Last = LOW;
boolean button1Current = LOW;
boolean button2Last = LOW;
boolean button2Current = LOW;


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPin1[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPin2[i], OUTPUT); 
  }
}

boolean waitForButtonPush1 (boolean lastStartSwitchState1)
{
  boolean currentStartSwitchState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  if(lastStartSwitchState1 != currentStartSwitchState1) delay(20);
  currentStartSwitchState1 = digitalRead(button1);
  return currentStartSwitchState1;
}

boolean waitForButtonPush2 (boolean lastStartSwitchState2)
{
  boolean currentStartSwitchState2 = digitalRead(button2);
  if(lastStartSwitchState2 != currentStartSwitchState2) delay(20);
  currentStartSwitchState2 = digitalRead(button2);
  return currentStartSwitchState2;
}

void loop() 
{
  button1Current = waitForButtonPush1(button1Last);
  if(button1Last == LOW && button1Current == HIGH)
  {
    for (byte counter =0;counter<=15; counter++)
  {
    displayBinary(counter);
    delay(500);
  }
  }
  button2Current = waitForButtonPush2(button2Last);
  if(button2Last == LOW && button2Current == HIGH)
  {
    for (byte counter =0;counter<=15; counter++)
  {
    displayBinary2(counter);
    delay(500);
    
  }
  }
}

void displayBinary(byte numToShow)
{
  for (int i =0;i<4;i++)
  {
    if (bitRead(numToShow, i)==1)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin1[i], HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin1[i], LOW);
      
    }
  }

}

void displayBinary2(byte numToShow)
{
  for (int i =0;i<4;i++)
  {
    if (bitRead(numToShow, i)==1)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin2[i], HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin2[i], LOW);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of embedded devices!

Getting a small microprocessor to do several things at the same time is a bit tricky.

The key is to never block.  No calls to delay(), no sending large buffers on the serial port at 9600 bauds in one go, etc...

There are some simple techniques to do it, one of the most commonly used is finite state machines.

Let's analyse your app a bit.

- 2 similar dssplay counters, with delay
- 2 buttons, buttons usually need to be debounced, that also involves a delay.

Some code, for you to tinker with:

```
// ****************************
// pinout

static const byte ledPin1[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
static const byte ledPin2[] = { 7, 8, 9, 10 };

constexpr byte button1 = 11;   // using constexpr for these saves 2 bytes of RAM.
constexpr byte button2 = 12;

// ****************************
// Counter data 

static constexpr unsigned int led_delay = 500;  // 500 ms, for all counters.

// constexpr ??  arduino supports c++17.  Not all features in the main .ino 
// module and all features in .cpp modules.  

// Hint: you could have a member variable in the structure below for delay, 
// this would allow for counters running at different speeds, or add buttons
// to increase/decrease speed.

// we have only 2 states, but you could add more, like running
// backwards, or run a different chase pattern maybe?

enum class led_counter_state : byte
{
    stopped,
    running,
};

struct led_counter_data_t
{
    led_counter_state state; // STATE
    byte counter;            // counter current value 
    unsigned int timestamp;  // used for timing.
    const byte* leds;        // LED pins.
};

static led_counter_data_t led_counter[2];

void led_display_init()
{
    for (byte i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        led_counter[i].state     = led_counter_state::stopped;
        led_counter[i].counter   = 0;
        led_counter[i].timestamp = 0;
    }
   led_counter[0].leds = ledPin1;
   led_counter[1].leds = ledPin2;   
}

// ****************************
// LED cotrrol

static void leds_display_value(const led_counter_data_t& cntr)
{
    for (byte i = 0, val = cntr.counter; i < 4; ++i, val >>= 1)
         digitalWrite(cntr.leds[i], val & 0x01);
}

static void leds_control(led_counter_data_t& cntr)
{
    const auto now = (unsigned int)millis();   // keep track of time.

    switch(cntr.state)
    {
    default:   // something is wrong.. stop.
        cntr.state = led_counter_state::stopped;

        // fall through ...

    case led_counter_state::stopped:
        return;                       // if not running, do nothing

    case led_counter_state::running:
        if (now - cntr.timestamp >= led_delay) // check delay
        {
            if (++cntr.counter > 15)           // advance counter.
                cntr.counter = 0;

            leds_display_value(cntr);           // show value.
            cntr.timestamp = now;              // keep track of time.
        }
        break;
    }
}

static void leds_start(led_counter_data_t& cntr)
{
    if (cntr.state != led_counter_state::stopped)
        return;

    cntr.state = led_counter_state::running;

    if (++cntr.counter > 15)  // advance counter.
        cntr.counter = 0;

    led_display_value(cntr);  // show value.

    cntr.timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
}

static void leds_stop(led_counter_data_t& cntr)
{
    cntr.state = led_counter_state::stopped;
}

// ****************************
//  switch inputs data

static constexpr byte switch_debounce_delay = 30;  // 30ms is a good value for
                                                   // debouncing
struct switch_data_t
{
    byte sw1_state : 1;  // no need to waste more than 1 bit per switch 
    byte sw2_state : 1;
    byte timestamp;      // we'll only count to 30 ms, so 1 byte timestamp will do
};

static switch_data_t switch_data;

// ****************************
//  switch inputs code

static void control_inputs()
{
    const auto now = (byte)millis();

    if (now - switch_data.timestamp < switch_debounce_delay)
        return;

    switch_data.timestamp = now;

    // All switch control logic is regrouped here, and isolated 
    // form other control code, this makes the logic easier to
    // write, read, and debug.  

    bool b = digitalRead(button1);
    if (b & !switch_data.sw1_state)   // button was pushed right now.
    {
        if (led_counter[0].state == led_counter_state::stopped)
        {
            leds_start(led_counter[0]);   // start counter 1
            leds_stop(led_counter[1]);    // stop counter 2
        }
        else
        {
            leds_stop(led_counter[0]);    // stop counter 1
        }
    }
    switch_data.sw1_state = b;

    b = digitalRead(button2);
    if (b & !switch_data.sw2_state)   // button was pushed right now.
    {
        if (led_counter[1].state == led_counter_state::stopped)
        {
            leds_start(led_counter[1]);   // start counter 2
            leds_stop(led_counter[0]);    // stop counter 1
        }
        else
        {
            leds_stop(led_counter[1]);    // stop counter 2
        }
    }
    switch_data.sw2_state = b;
}

// ****************************

void setup()
{
    pinMode(button1, INPUT);
    pinMode(button2, INPUT);
 
    for (byte i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin1[i], LOW);
        pinMode(ledPin1[i], OUTPUT);

        digitalWrite(ledPin2[i], LOW);
        pinMode(ledPin2[i], OUTPUT);
    }

    led_display_init();
}

// ****************************
// The goal, always, is to exit loop() as fast as possible, so 
// everything will run smoothly, and appear to run simultaneously.

void loop()
{
    control_inputs();
    leds_control(led_counter[0]);
    leds_control(led_counter[1]);
}
```

I do not have an arduino with me, so I did not comppile nor ran this, but it should be pretty close.  Let me know if you're having issues or have any questions.